# How to use "view" option of XML starlet?

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

I am trying to select values from an XML by `XPath`. I wonder *why*`xmlstarlet sel -t -m //data -v "." /tmp/test.xml` *does* work and `xmlstarlet sel -t -m //data /tmp/test.xml` *does not*.

I know that option `-v` means *view*. However `xmlstarlet sel -t -m //data -v /tmp/test.xml` is getting stuck.

So, my question is how to use option *view* properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `-v` means *value-of* and `-m` means *for-each*. These refer to the [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) definitions<sup>*</sup>, since the sel subcommand simply generates an XSLT document and runs it on the input.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //data /tmp/test.xml
```

This is a loop without a body, so there is no output.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //data -v /tmp/test.xml
```

Here `/tmp/test.xml` is interpreted as the XPath expression to `-v` so this means: for-each data node, output the value-of nodes named `test.xml` beneath the `tmp` root node. And it expects the input XML to come from standard input so it will appear to be stuck.

You can always get the meaning of any `sel` command line as XSLT by using the `-C` option.

---

* In recent versions of xmlstarlet (1.3+) `-v` will output the value-of each node in a nodelist separated by a newline, rather than the XSLT definition where value-of only outputs the string value of the first node.

Comment: Well, *match*, but yes, it does the equivalent of a for-each.